# Is there a way to use an alias as a part of a command?

Tags: alias, csh

i.e. I have an alias in my .cshrc file

```
alias foo = /Users/name/documents
```

and i want to do something like

```
mv foobar.txt foo
```

but this just renames foobar.txt to foo.

Also tried

```
mv footbar.txt $foo
```

to no avail.

I think I can create a script to take in a path and filename and alias instead to the script, but is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why do you have the path stored as an alias and not an environment variable?

Comment: Turns out environment variables are what I was looking for lol.  Thanks.